# How to validate a link is clicked or not in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form and I am validating all the input tags by the angular messages, but there is a link on click of that link form gets expanded, but initially the form will be hidden.

So if user is clicking submit button, he should get an error saying please click the link to fill more details.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.0" data-semver="1.11.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="myContoller">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form role="form" name="memberForm" ng-submit="submitMemberForm()" novalidate="">
          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':(memberForm.loginName.$touched || memberForm.$submitted ) && memberForm.loginName.$invalid}">
            <label for="userName" ng-hide="(memberForm.loginName.$touched || memberForm.$submitted ) && memberForm.loginName.$invalid ">User Name</label>
            <label class="help-block" ng-messages="memberForm.loginName.$error" ng-show="(memberForm.loginName.$touched || memberForm.$submitted ) && memberForm.loginName.$invalid">
              <p ng-message="required">User name is required.</p>
              <p ng-message="maxlength">maxlength</p>
              <p ng-message="minlength">minlength</p>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control " ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10" id="userName" name="loginName" ng-model="login.name" required/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.postcode.$invalid && (memberForm.postcode.$touched || memberForm.$submitted) }">
            <label for="PostCode" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.postcode.$invalid  && (memberForm.postcode.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Postcode*<a style="margin-left:20px;" href="" ng-click="ShowHide()">Address Search</a></label>
            <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.postcode.$invalid  &&  (memberForm.postcode.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Postcode is a mandatory field</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control " ng-model="postcode" ng-maxlength="9" required>
          </div>

          <div ng-show="IsVisible">

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.address.$invalid && ( memberForm.address.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)}">
              <label for="Contact address" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.address.$invalid && ( memberForm.address.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Contact address*</label>
              <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.address.$invalid && ( memberForm.address.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Contact address is required</label>
              <div class="clearfix">
                <select name="address" id="address" ng-model="user.address" class="form-control " required>
                  <option value="0">Address 1</option>
                  <option value="1">Address 2</option>
                  <option value="2">Address 3</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.town.$invalid && (memberForm.town.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)}">
              <label for="Town" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.town.$invalid  && (memberForm.town.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted )">Town*</label>
              <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.town.$invalid  &&  (memberForm.town.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted)"> Town is a mandatory field</label>
              <input type="text" name="town" class="form-control " ng-model="user.town" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.country.$invalid && (memberForm.country.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)}">
              <label for="Country" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.country.$invalid  && (memberForm.country.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted )">Country*</label>
              <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.country.$invalid  &&  (memberForm.country.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted)"> Country is a mandatory field</label>
              <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control " ng-model="user.country" required>
            </div>

          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="sbt" class="btn-success btn">SUBMIT</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Then he should be filing the expanded form.

[I have attached Plunker, on filing postcode and submitting the form it should ask me to click on address link to fill rest.](https://plnkr.co/edit/qNYzNTlX53lH2DY38m1x?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a boolean variable to display or hide the warning message.
I edited your plunker and you can find it at the following link [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/envvuXSGjO69CkJ23FEE).

```
$scope.showErrorMsg
```

is a boolean variable to help keep tracking if show or hide the error message.

```
$scope.IsVisible
```

is used to keep track if the user clicked on the link AND all mandatory fields are filled. If all field are filled and the user click the link, the div is displayed and the error message disappear.

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages'])
.controller('myContoller', function ($scope) {
  

   $scope.showErrorMsg = false;
   
   $scope.ShowHide = function () {
 
    
    if($scope.postcode) {
        //If DIV is hidden it will be visible 
        $scope.IsVisible = true;
        $scope.showErrorMsg = false;

    }
 }
  
  
  $scope.submitMemberForm=function(){
     
     
     if (!$scope.IsVisible){
       // display error message 
       $scope.showErrorMsg = true;
       return;
     }
     
     $scope.submitMemberForm.$submitted=true;
      if($scope.memberForm.$valid){
    
      alert("Success");

}
}
  
  
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.has-error .help-block{
  
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.0" data-semver="1.11.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.8/angular-messages.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="myContoller">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form role="form" name="memberForm" ng-submit="submitMemberForm()" novalidate="">
          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':(memberForm.loginName.$touched || memberForm.$submitted ) && memberForm.loginName.$invalid}">
            <label for="userName" ng-hide="(memberForm.loginName.$touched || memberForm.$submitted ) && memberForm.loginName.$invalid ">User Name</label>
            <label class="help-block" ng-messages="memberForm.loginName.$error" ng-show="(memberForm.loginName.$touched || memberForm.$submitted ) && memberForm.loginName.$invalid">
              <p ng-message="required">User name is required.</p>
              <p ng-message="maxlength">maxlength</p>
              <p ng-message="minlength">minlength</p>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control "  ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10" id="userName" name="loginName" ng-model="login.name" required/>
          </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.postcode.$invalid && (memberForm.postcode.$touched || memberForm.$submitted) }">
                    <label for="PostCode"  class="" >Postcode*<a style="margin-left:20px;" href="" ng-click="ShowHide()">Address Search</a></label>
                    <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.postcode.$invalid  &&  (memberForm.postcode.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Postcode is a mandatory field</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="postcode" class="form-control " ng-model="postcode" ng-maxlength="9" required>
     </div>

          <div  ng-show="IsVisible">

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.address.$invalid && ( memberForm.address.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)}">
              <label for="Contact address" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.address.$invalid && ( memberForm.address.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Contact address*</label>
              <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.address.$invalid && ( memberForm.address.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)">Contact address is required</label>
              <div class="clearfix">
                <select name="address" id="address" ng-model="user.address" class="form-control " required>
                  <option value="0">Address 1</option>
                   <option value="1">Address 2</option>
                    <option value="2">Address 3</option>
                  

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
           

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.town.$invalid && (memberForm.town.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)}">
              <label for="Town" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.town.$invalid  && (memberForm.town.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted )">Town*</label>
              <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.town.$invalid  &&  (memberForm.town.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted)"> Town is a mandatory field</label>
              <input type="text" name="town" class="form-control " ng-model="user.town" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : memberForm.country.$invalid && (memberForm.country.$touched || memberForm.$submitted)}">
              <label for="Country" class="" ng-hide="memberForm.country.$invalid  && (memberForm.country.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted )">Country*</label>
              <label class="help-block" ng-show="memberForm.country.$invalid  &&  (memberForm.country.$touched|| memberForm.$submitted)"> Country is a mandatory field</label>
              <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control " ng-model="user.country" required>
            </div>

          </div>

          <label class="help-block" ng-show="showErrorMsg">Please click the link</label>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="sbt" class="btn-success btn">SUBMIT</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

A very-very simple solution is to give the form a name so you can refer to it and then tweak the `ng-click` to fire only if the form is valid:

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" ng-model='name' ng-required="true" />
    <button ng-click="myform.$valid && preview()">Preview</button>
    <button ng-click="myform.$valid && update()">Update</button>
</form>
```

Forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8d1uq0L/

I like separating validation (a business concern) from the view, to that end I created [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron) that lets you define the model constraints in code and use programmatic validation along with standard Angular form validation.